Abstract Cauchy problem: existence of solution
Let us take an abstract ODE
$$ \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
\dot f(t) = A f(t), \\
f(0) = f_0
\end{array}\right.$$ on a Hilbert space $X$. The operator $A$ is linear, closed and densely defined on $X$. The associated semigroup $(T(t))_{t\geq 0}$ is bounded on $X$. Until now, I cannot prove the strong continuity of the semigroup on $X$.
However, there is a dense subspace $D\subseteq dom(A)$ which is $T(t)-$invariant ($T(t) x \in D, \forall t\geq 0, \forall x\in D$) on which I have the strong continuity. But I cannot show that $T(t)$ is uniformly bounded near $0$.
Is it possible to prove (or hope for) the existence and the uniqueness of a weak-solution for the abstract Cauchy-problem, for any initial value in $D$ ?
Note that $D$ is clearly not complete.
